# Finding a quantity of anything between two points in space

Tags: plot, 3d, grid, geometry, latitude-longitude

I'm currently working towards a 3D model of this, but I thought I would start with 2D. Basically, I have a grid of longitude and latitude with NO2 concentrations across it. What I want to produce, at least for now, is a total amount of Nitrogen Dioxide between two points. Like so:
[2DGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhOaZ.jpg)

Basically, These two points are at different lats and lons and as I stated I want to find the amount of something between them. The tricky thing to me is that the model data I'm working with is gridded so I need to be able to account for the amount of something along a line at the lat and lons at which that line cuts through said grid.

Another approach, and maybe a better one for my purposes, could be visualized like this:[3DGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gQC8.png)

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to create a program (within any language honestly) that could find the amount of "something" between two points in a 3D grid. If you would like specfics, the bottom altitude is the surface, the top grid is the top of the atmosphere. The bottom point is a measurement device looking at the sun during a certain time of day (and therefore having a certain zenith and azimuth angle). I want to find the NO2 between that measurement device and the "top of the atmosphere" which in my grid is just the top altitude level (of which there are 25).

I'm rather new to coding, stack exchange, and even the subject matter I'm working with so the sparse code I've made might end up creating more clutter than purely asking the question and seeing what methods/code you might suggest?

Hopefully my question is beneficial!

Best,
Taylor

Comment: And how should quantity of NO2 be calculated? Summing values for all touched cells?

Comment: We have a model field that has the NO2 values already. We're looking to sum the values for touched cells/ Values that touch the line, but these values are at very specific latitudes/longitudes so it shouldn't be a huge issue.

Comment: For some cells line passes through center, some are slightly touched. There is no difference in counting quantities?

Comment: Sorry, I think you're right. Yes, there is a difference in counting quantities based on what distance of the line passes through each grid. So yes, the longer the vector in each cell, the more data from that cell passes through. Thank you for mentioning this, I didn't think of it!

Comment: This has been [cross-posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3109215/35416) to Math SE. Please [don't do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/188688)! Ask in the most suitable community, then stick with that. And always mention any related questions via links, so people get the full picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To traverse all touched cells, you can use Amanatides-Woo [algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2611491_A_Fast_Voxel_Traversal_Algorithm_for_Ray_Tracing). It is suitable both for 2D and for 3D case.

[image]

[Implementation clues](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Raytracing_Topics_Techniques-Part_4_Spatial_Subdivisions.shtml)

To account for quantity used from every cell, you can apply some model. For example, calculate path length inside cell (as difference of enter and exit coordinates) and divide by normalizing factor to get cell weight (for example, by`CellSize*Sqrt(3)` for 3D case as diagonal length).

Comment: Holy cow this is awesome! I tried it on my 2D case that I fabricated and it seemed to work. I'll try it on the 3D case too!